# What difference index.php vs index.blade.php in laravel?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

The file can have any of those two extensions: .php or .blade.php? true or false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're both php scripts. However, the Laravel Templates documentation page states that all Blade templates should use the .blade.php extension. If you rename the script to just .php your templates will not work as expected and will only output the contents of the script and execute any php code in there.

Comment: ah that making sense to me, it happened to me when I put like .blade.php of AngularJs syntax. so I have to change to .php file. I had to put @include('angular.php') separate the file.

Answer (score 1):

Actually main difference between `xxx.blade.php` and `xxx.php` is files ending in `.blade.php` will allow you to use the Blade templating language while "normal" `.php` files won't.

Using PHP codes in both files with the usual.